# Calling Excel Macro from Outlook 16

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am running into some headaches to call a Excel Macro contained in my personal.xlsm please assist me.

I am running Outlook 2016. Attempting to call macros from personal.xlsm on opening Outlook. The key issue (I think based on other solutions) is the correct Excel Data object library isn't included but I've included what appears to be the relevant ones (without success).

[image: Includes]

The program just runs over the line without calling the Macro - I've placed a MsgBox prompt at the start of the Excel Macro to check if it starts to run & fails everytime.

Extract from code below; I've remove code not relevant to this problem.

In outlook: ThisSession

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()


Dim macroFile As String, networkFilePath As String, sourceFile as String
Dim DestFile As String: DestFile = "FolderTree.csv"
Dim SourceFolder As String: SourceFolder = "[NetworkLocation]"
Dim foldersRequired As String

Dim objShell As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim fso As FileSystemObject:  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim xlApp As Object: Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   'open the excel csv source file
Dim xlWkb As Object, xlSht As Object

On Error Resume Next

''get the core xlsb macros file - saves updating the individual user outlook
macroFile = userProfilePath & "\Personal.xlsb"
'This works fine & opens the file with no issues.

 Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(macroFile)
 Set xlSht = xlWkb.Worksheets(1) 
xlApp.Application.Visible = True

'' extract the users profile path
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    userProfilePath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%") & "[DataFolder]"

sourceFile = userProfilePath & "\" & DestFile


xlApp.Workbooks("Personal.xlsb").Activate
xlApp.Workbooks.Open FileName:=(sourceFile)
'' This opens fine

If Not xlxApp Is Nothing Then
     '' None of the below work
     xlWkb.Application.Run "Module1.Clean_CSV(sourceFile, userProfilePath)"
     '' This doesn't work
     xlWkb.Application.Run "Personal.xlsb!Module1.Clean_CSV(sourceFile, userProfilePath)"
     '' This doesn't work
     xlWkb.Application.Run "Personal.xlsb!Clean_CSV(sourceFile, userProfilePath)"
     '' This doesn't work
End If
     xlApp.Close
     xlApp.Quit

     '' I set all Variables & Objects to Nothing & then
End Sub
```

[Screenshot of Excel Test Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR9qR.png)

Comment: Seems that you never set the value of `macrofile`.  Have you stepped through this using the debugger?  Also, if you're using the Excel 16 Object library, you can set the xlApp, xlWkb etc as Excel Objects, not 'object'.  Have you tried commenting-out the `On Error Resume Next` to see if it has an error (I expect to see a 'file not found' one trying to open macrofile).

Comment: You are passing a string to `Application.Run`.  Within that string you are trying to set some parameters for your Excel macro, but you are passing names of variables that exist in the Outlook application, not in the Excel application.  I suspect you will need to use something of the form `"Personal.xlsb!Module1.Clean_CSV(""" & sourceFile & """,""" &  userProfilePath & """)"` so that the values are passed as part of the string.

Comment: And, as @ainwood points out, you aren't setting `macroFile` until **after** you have attempted to open the workbook.  (But maybe `Personal.xlsb` gets opened automatically anyway, simply by opening Excel.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Noting comment that the macroFile is being opened before being defined - in my entire code this is done in the correct order, but my input error for above. Ive fixed this for reference.

Comment: @YowE3k. I'm not sure that I follow you. I am [attempting] to pass into the Excel Macro the value of the variable, not the variable itself.  If I use the quotation marks as you have noted, will this not pass the **name** of the variable rather than the **variable value**?
@niton; thanks. This hasn't fixed anything though. When I have put a capture for the error `RunExcelMacro_Err: MsgBox Err.Description` I get thrown the error "Object required"

Comment: If, for instance, `sourceFile` had the value of `abc` and `userProfilePath` had the value of `xyz`, then `"Personal.xlsb!Module1.Clean_CSV(""" & sourceFile & """,""" & userProfilePath & """)"` will equate to `"Personal.xlsb!Module1.Clean_CSV(""abc"",""xyz"")"`, i.e. the string `Personal.xlsb!Module1.Clean_CSV("abc","xyz")`.  Your `"Personal.xlsb!Module1.Clean_CSV(sourceFile, userProfilePath)"` would just give the string `Personal.xlsb!Module1.Clean_CSV(sourceFile, userProfilePath)`.  `xlApp` will have no idea what `sourceFile` and `userProfilePath` are and therefore give an error. (I think!)

Comment: I follow you now; but if passing between Macros then the quotation marks are not required. Eg,I  am current passing between two macros the same string noted above & there is no requirement to add the quotations as the variable passes the string or integer just fine.
Its not so much the variables aren't being passed correctly into the macro, the macro doesn't run at all. I put a `MsgBox "Excel Macros Running"` just as a check & this doesn't show at all & the file that I'm passing in that I want to "Clean" (remove the data I don't want/need) doesn't open or the cleaned file then exist/save etc.

Comment: Just as a test, create an Excel subroutine that requires no parameters to be passed to it (e.g. `Sub TestMe()` `MsgBox "Hello"` `End Sub`).  Try running that from Outlook (probably using `xlWkb.Application.Run "Personal.xlsb!Module1.TestMe()"`) and see whether you can get it to work.  Once that is working, we can worry about the parameters.

Comment: Getting closer, now getting error runtime '1004': Cannot run the macro  'Personal.xlsb!MessageMe()'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled. 
In this instance I have enabled all macros in trust centre so it is not disabled & have tried with the macro in ThisWorkbook as well as Module1. It is a Public Sub, not Private.  I have appended a screen shot of macro above.